# does anyone know how to use colorcodes instead of just assigning colors with UIColor

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Like the title says I want to use a color code instead of doing something like this

```
lblTemp.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0 green:0x99/255.0 blue:0 alpha:1.0];
```

for instance I have the following colorcode    #30ae36  how can I use this one instead of doing the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this handy macro:

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor \
colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

(I might have gotten it [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243201/is-macro-better-than-uicolor-for-setting-rgb-color), but you can find it in many places. In any case it's worth reading the discussion about macros vs inline functions at this link.)

If you want to initialize the color from a string (for example from a plist), you can use this:

```
unsigned    rgbValues;
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:@"0xFF0000"] scanHexInt: &rgbValues];
UIColor* redColor = UIColorFromRGB(rgbValues);
```

Answer (score 2):

UIColor doesn't offer a default method for that, but, you could create a so called [category](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/macsploitation/extending-classes-in-objectivec-with-categories-27447) for UIColor which takes the hex value (sans the #) and turns it in to the corresponding RGB components and uses those components to feed to UIColor's colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:.

Comment: it's been figured out.... I'm blind as a bat I'll post the answer below 
Thanks for your input though

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick for this code #30ae36

```
lblTemp4.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0x*30*/255.0 green:0x*AE*/255.0 blue:0x*36*/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the previous answer, from *jovany* the *  * stars should be omitted. So #30ae36 becomes:

```
lblTemp4.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0x30/255.0 green:0xAE/255.0 blue:0x36/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

(Maybe obvious, but I didn´t get it at first sight)