# What is the data type of a hex value like 0xD2691E?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, c

I'm trying to write a method which takes in a hex value such as `0xD2691E` for the purpose of returning a UIColor object.

I [found this macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805177/how-to-convert-hex-rgb-color-codes-to-uicolor) which I want to convert into a method, but I don't know how to specify the data type other than `void *`.

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor \
       colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
       green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
       blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]

  //Then use any Hex value

 self.view.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xD2691E);
```

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243201/is-macro-better-than-uicolor-for-setting-rgb-color

Answer (score 12):

> What is the data type of a hex value like `0xD2691E`?

According to C standard, the type of an hexadecimal constant is the first of this list in which its value can be represented:

> #### C11 (n1570), § 6.4.4.1 Integer constants
>
> ```
> int
> unsigned int
> long int
> unsigned long int
> long long int
> unsigned long long int
> ```

Since `D2691E` (b16) is equal to `13789470` (b10), the type of your constant depends on your implementation.

C standard only guarantees that `INT_MAX >= +32767`, whereas `LONG_MAX >= +2147483647`.

> #### C11 (n1570), 5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types
>
> - `INT_MAX +32767`
> - `LONG_MAX +2147483647`

Therefore, `(unsigned) long int` could be a suitable choice.

Comment: iOS uses the ILP32 architecture, so both int and long are 32-bit here (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iPhoneOSABIReference/Articles/ARMv6FunctionCallingConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009021-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

from what i remembered they are something like int or unsigned int.

Comment: Both will do for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use this one.....

```
    unsigned long long 
    unsigned long int
```

Comment: So you say it'2 an unsigned long long ull?

Answer (score 0):

In this method, they perform bitwise `AND` operation, so it must be `unsigned of int  OR long`